# Merging two files on a common column and printing all columns using awk

Tags: bash, unix, join, awk

i have two very long space-separated files that look somehow like this:

file1:

```
CHR SNP   A1 A2 MAF
1    rs12  A G  0.43
1    rs1   A T  0.22
1    1:30  G A  0.012
1    rs23  G A  0.012
```

file2:

```
SNP    CHR A1 A2 MAF CHR:BP
rs21   1   G  A  0.03 1:30
rs13   1   T  A  0.06 1:122
rs23   1   A  G  0.02 1:234
```

I want to merge them together, when column 2 from file 1 either fits with column 1 from file 2 or with column 6 from file 2 and print all columns from both files.

so my output for the example should be:
file 3

```
SNP  CHR A1 A2 MAF CHR:BP CHR SNP  A1 A2 MAF
rs21 1   G  A  0.03 1:30   1  1:30 G  A  0.012
rs23 1   A  G  0.02 1:234  1  rs23 G  A  0.012
```

i used the following code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next} ($1 in a || $6 in a){print $0 FS a[$2]}' file1 file2 > file3
```

But for some reason it filters out the right lines but only prints the columns of file2 but not of file1.

I also tried with join, but it gives me weird results, even when the files are sorted. Weird meaning, that it ommits roughly 1/5 of the lines that actually are present in both files. But just for completion, this is the code I tried using join:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 -o '2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 2.10 2.11 2.12 2.13 2.14 2.15 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6' <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k1 file2) > file3.1

join -1 2 -2 6 -o '2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 2.10 2.11 2.12 2.13 2.14 2.15 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6' <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k6 file2) > file3.2

cat file3.1 file 3.2 > file3
```

Does anybody see my mistake? I would be very greatful.
Thanks!

Comment: Think about it - you're checking that a[$1] or a[$6] exists but then printing a[**$2**].

Comment: I guess, I got something completely wrong about the logic of my statement. I thought of it like this: I save $2 of file 1 in an array a, at each entry I save the whole line (a[$2]=$0). Then I check whether $1 or $6 of file 2 is present in the array a. If yes, I print the whole line ($0) of file2 and the whole line at each fitting entry of the array a.

Comment: Right but when you were reading file1 the $2 of the current line had some value like rs21 and then when you're reading file2 it's $1 or $6 of the line in file2 that has the value rs21, not $2 of the line in file2 which has some completely different value like `1`. You obviously knew that when you wrote the test code `$1 in a || $6 in a` and that hasn't changed when you then want to print `a[rs21]`.

Comment: What should the output be if $1 and $6 from file2 are BOTH present as $2s in file1 but for different lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in your `print` command:

```
{print $0 FS a[$2]}
```

should be

```
{print $0, ( $1 in a ? a[$1] : a[$6] )}
```

because (1) the "interesting" field is only in `$2` while you're in file1, not as you traverse `file2`, and (2) you need to pull data from the array based on either of your conditions. We can select which array element using a classic ternary operator. (I've added extra spacing for easier reading.)

Note the use of the comma, which separates fields by `OFS`, rather than using `FS` which is your input field separator.

Otherwise, your code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$0;next} ($1 in a) || ($6 in a){print $0,a[$1]?a[$1]:a[$6]}'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution here too.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$2]=$0
  next
}
($1 in a) || ($6 in a){
  print $0,a[$1]?a[$1]:a[$6]
}'  Input_file1   Input_file2
```

Append `> file3` to above ones to get the output into file3.

***EDIT:*** Adding solution for OP's code too now.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next} ($1 in a || $6 in a){print $0 FS a[$1]?a[$1]:a[$6]}' file1 file2 > file3
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick and helpful answer. It works! Could you explain why my awk solution didnt work? I still dont see the error.
And what is your solution actually checking- I dont quite understand the syntax.

Comment: @Aron, please check my EDIT now too.

Comment: @Aron, looks like my provided code itself is your code's solution itself :)

Comment: I mean, not quite- your printing command is doing the trick.
Why did you in your edit print a[$2] instead of a[$1] as you had it in your first solution? (The first one seems to be the correct one?)

Comment: @Aron, I was just trying to fix your problem of `a[$2]` and `a[$6]` problem, you could change it too actual `$1` let me do so now.